# Python 3 - Router Access

Tags: python

I have been using the following script to grab the PIN from our router. It is changed often so I decided to use a script so it would be easier than having to access the router from the browser.

The script is as follows:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import re

while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get('http://192.168.2.1/settings.html', 
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
        html = response.content
        m = re.findall(b'var routerpin\s+=\s+(.*)', html)
        break
    except:
        m = None

print(m)
```

The trouble I am having is the first time the script is run the variable 'm' returns an empty list. It does not give an exception. I thought by using a try - except loop and using the None or empty set as the exception would allow it to work.

When the script runs once it returns m = []
after this the script returns the correct data. I know this is down to the first run not authenticating with the router but not sure how I can handle it to run twice and grab the data.

Probably a really simple answer but any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a session object to manage your authenticated session:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('username', 'password')
auth = s.post('http://192.168.2.1')
response = s.get('http://192.168.2.1/settings.html')
html = response.content
# etc
```

Comment: this has thrown three exceptions when I run it. http.client.BadStatusLine:, urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError:, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection Aborted

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what is wrong. But if your code always succeeds on the second run you could try simply running the request twice before processing the response.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the issue by forcing an indexerror when the list is returned empty, then contained it in a try except loop.